# How do I fit any image to my window using tkinter and PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to make an image viewer app, but the problem is that sometimes the images are large, and *the window will auto-resize itself to fit the image*; hence, the buttons that I've made are overshadowed by the image.

Say, I have fixed my window size by using the `window.geometry("sizexsize")`, how then can I make the images adjust to the window, and not the other way around?

The program looks like these when run (some have buttons, some do not):

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjZit.jpg
[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1VDk.jpg

Comment: Use another module to resize the image after loading, prior to placing it on the canvas. Take a look a `PIL (Python Imaging Library)` for `Image` and `ImageTk`

Comment: Yes. I have imported the Pillow library already, but I just started using it. I actually tried resizing one of the images by using the (height=x, width=x) arguments, but it doesn't seem to be efficient, and I also think my usage of it is wrong.

Comment: @LuckyJones Maybe you should show us the usage of PIL then

Answer (score 1):

If you have `height` and `width` you can resize the images with Pillow:

```
load = Image.open(path_to_image)
load = load.resize((width, height))

render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)

img = tk.Label(image=render)
img.image = render
img.place(x=0, y=0)
```